# How to localize web.sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement localization in web.sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614484/how-to-implement-localization-in-web-sitemap)

i have one sitemap file
this is a part of sitemap file

My resource file name is globalres.resx

any one tell me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

Add a resourceKey, found in the global resource file, to the siteMapNodes.